# How to run a script, command or exe file, when login windows?

Tags: windows

How to run a script, command or exe file, when login windows?

Windows system:

I already know that there is a task schedule in the windows. And I create the task which will be triggered when user login. **This task will pop up a message box.**

The script(*The msgbox pop up*) work fine when the PC is started at the first time.

But when you use the `win+L` to lock the PC, the msgbox will not show up.
Is there a way to implement my requirement?

---

### **Update**

According to the answer of the @Christian H . I already make the config in the GPO done. And I create a new task in the schedule, but I don't know which `log` and `source` to choose?

Cuz the language I use is CHN, here is the *translation*.

```
         触发器: **trigger**

         当事件被记录时: **When the event is recorded**

         日志: **log**

         源: **source**

         事件ID : **event ID**
```

I can't post the img now, since I haven't got 10 reputation.
So, here is the img link:

**http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/11~29_15-26-45.bmp**

Comment: What version of WIndows are you using? On my Win 7 box, one of the possible Task Triggers listed is "When I log on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating two triggers in the task scheduler the first one triggered by "At log in" and triggered by "On workstation unlock" actions launch my program. Not sure of another way...

Kind Regards

Comment: I can't find the trigger named '*On workstation unlock*'

Comment: What version of windows are you using? This should be there on at least windows 7 and later. only other thing I can think of are you creating a "new task" or "new basic task" don't think the option is there with a basic task

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to make sure you're auditing the unlock events, which isn't on by default.

In the GPO, enable *Computer Config > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy > System Audit Policy > Logon/Logoff > Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events*

Once that's done, make a trigger that looks for Event ID 4801 in the Security log, and it should catch it.  As someone else mentioned, you'll need another trigger for logon if you want it to happen then too.

Comment: I update the post according to your post, but I still have some problems. Plz read it~. I don't know how to choose the `source` or `log` here~

Comment: Both Log and Source should be "Security"

Comment: doesn't work for me. I already set the `log` and `source` as `Security`